# How to update parent row of hierarchical grid in response to checkbox click when there are more than one child row?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Kendo UI MVC
Have implemented a hierarchical grid and now need to respond to an event on a checkbox within the child rows.  Ive seen examples of using the "next tr", but does this still apply if the child grid has more than one row and im responding to an event on the 2nd row of the child grid?

Within a ClientTemplate for column, Im wanting to call a javascript function, but I need to pass a reference to the current row the checkbox is in.  What do I use to pass.

eg. I need to pass a reference to the current row that has the checkbox as a parameter of the applyLedger javascript function.  How do I get a reference to the row within a template?  Or, am I going about this the hard way, and maybe should look at using a different type of kendo object?

```
            columns.Bound(order => order.Enabled).Title("Apply").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).ClientTemplate("<input id='applyWarehouse' type='checkbox' onclick='applyLedger(this, #= OrderID #, \"\\#= OrderNumber\\#\");' class='chkbx' \\#= Enabled ? checked='checked' : '' \\# />").Width(5);
```

[ **update** ]

After reading Joe's response below, here is how I grabbed the parent row of the PARENT grid containing the row that checkbox is in.

```
                    function applyLedger(e) {
  var tr = $(e).closest("tr"); // get the row containing the checkbox
  var data = $("#my-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(tr); // get the data model
  // do business stuff using data ...

  // get parent row of detail grid
  var parentRow = tr.closest("tr");
  var parentRowData = $("#my-parent-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(parentRow);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there; I think provided that you can get a reference to the control which raised the click event within your event handler, the easiest approach will always be to climb the DOM using jquery and locate your `tr` from within the function, rather than attempt to pass that knowledge in from outside.

Since you are passing `this` as the first parameter to `applyLedger`, the context within the click handler should be your checkbox in which case locating the `tr` should be as simple as:

```
function applyLedger(e) {
  var tr = $(e).closest("tr"); // get the row containing the checkbox
  var data = $("#my-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(tr); // get the data model
  // do business stuff using data ...
}
```

Note the code which interrogates the grid for the `data` model associated with the grid row, which makes passing the various properties in unnecessary. So your MVC code could be simplified as well:

```
.ClientTemplate("<input id='applyWarehouse' type='checkbox' onclick='applyLedger(this);' class='chkbx' \\#= Enabled ? checked='checked' : '' \\# />").Width(5);
```

As an aside, you should probably also remove the `id` from your checkbox template as well, as this is supposed to be unique on your page; consider using `name` instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, that helps.  however, the problem with the grid that the checkbox is in is within a clientdetailtemplate as part of a hierarchical grid.  So I need to get the row in the PARENT grid and update a few cells there also, but this helps a bunch and let me get the rest of the way.

Comment: Thanks, but I also needed the parent row of the parent grid.  However, with your help I was able to see the approach needed to get it.  See update in my post.